# SVC Unable to find the attributes '_probA'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am developing credit card fraud detections project in machine learning. I have download the code form GitHub (https://github.com/devrajkataria/Credit-Card-Fraud-Detection-ML-WebApp) but I am getting following errors:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute '_probA'
```

I tried to update the package but the did not work .I am using python version of 3.6. Here is the code.py

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
from sklearn.svm import SVC

    app = Flask(__name__)
    # prediction function 
    def ValuePredictor(to_predict_list): 
        to_predict = np.array(to_predict_list).reshape(1, 7) 
        loaded_model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb")) 
        result = loaded_model.predict(to_predict) 
        return result[0]     
        
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template("index.html")
    
    @app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
    def predict():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            to_predict_list = request.form.to_dict() 
            to_predict_list = list(to_predict_list.values()) 
            to_predict_list = list(map(float, to_predict_list))
            result = ValuePredictor(to_predict_list)
        if int(result)== 1:
            prediction ='Given transaction is fradulent'
        else:
            prediction ='Given transaction is NOT fradulent'            
        return render_template("result.html", prediction = prediction) 
               
                      
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the classifier code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Project_Final.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

# Data Preprocessing and Visualisation
"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
# %matplotlib inline

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import sklearn
import random

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
# %matplotlib inline

from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('creditcardfraud.zip','r') as zip:
  zip.printdir()
  zip.extractall()

d=pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv')

sns.distplot(data['Amount'])

sns.distplot(data['Time'])

data.hist(figsize=(20,20))
plt.show()

sns.jointplot(x= 'Time', y= 'Amount', data= d)

class0 = d[d['Class']==0]

len(class0)

class1 = d[d['Class']==1]

len(class1)

class0
temp = shuffle(class0)

d1 = temp.iloc[:2000,:]

d1

frames = [d1, class1]
df_temp = pd.concat(frames)

df_temp.info()

df= shuffle(df_temp)

df.to_csv('creditcardsampling.csv')

sns.countplot('Class', data=df)

"""# SMOTE"""

!pip install --user imblearn

import imblearn

from imblearn.over_sampling import  SMOTE
oversample=SMOTE()
X=df.iloc[ : ,:-1]
Y=df.iloc[: , -1]
X,Y=oversample.fit_resample(X,Y)

X=pd.DataFrame(X)
X.shape

Y=pd.DataFrame(Y)
Y.head()

names=['Time','V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10','V11','V12','V13','V14','V15','V16','V17','V18','V19','V20','V21','V22','V23','V24','V25','V26','V27','V28','Amount','Class']

data=pd.concat([X,Y],axis=1)

d=data.values

data=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=names)

sns.countplot('Class', data=data)

data.describe()

data.info()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
sns.heatmap(data.corr())

!pip install --user lightgbm

!pip install --user utils

import math
import sklearn.preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score , classification_report, confusion_matrix, precision_recall_curve, f1_score, auc

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.drop('Class', axis=1), data['Class'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

"""# Feature Scaling"""

cols= ['V22', 'V24', 'V25', 'V26', 'V27', 'V28']

scaler = StandardScaler()

frames= ['Time', 'Amount']

x= data[frames]

d_temp = data.drop(frames, axis=1)

temp_col=scaler.fit_transform(x)

scaled_col = pd.DataFrame(temp_col, columns=frames)

scaled_col.head()

d_scaled = pd.concat([scaled_col, d_temp], axis =1)

d_scaled.head()

y = data['Class']

d_scaled.head()

"""# Dimensionality Reduction"""

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=7)

X_temp_reduced = pca.fit_transform(d_scaled)

pca.explained_variance_ratio_

pca.explained_variance_

names=['Time','Amount','Transaction Method','Transaction Id','Location','Type of Card','Bank']

X_reduced= pd.DataFrame(X_temp_reduced,columns=names)
X_reduced.head()

Y=d_scaled['Class']

new_data=pd.concat([X_reduced,Y],axis=1)
new_data.head()
new_data.shape

new_data.to_csv('finaldata.csv')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X_reduced, d_scaled['Class'], test_size = 0.30, random_state = 42)

X_train.shape, X_test.shape

"""# Logistic Regression"""

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr=LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_lr=lr.predict(X_test)
y_pred_lr

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_lr))

#Hyperparamter tuning 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
lr_model = LogisticRegression()
lr_params = {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
grid_lr= GridSearchCV(lr_model, param_grid = lr_params)
grid_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

grid_lr.best_params_

y_pred_lr3=grid_lr.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_lr3))



"""# Support Vector Machine"""

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc=SVC(kernel='rbf')
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_svc=svc.predict(X_test)
y_pred_svc

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_svc))

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_svc))

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [ {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [0.1, 1, 0.01, 0.0001 ,0.001]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = svc,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           n_jobs = -1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
print("Best Accuracy: {:.2f} %".format(best_accuracy*100))
print("Best Parameters:", best_parameters)

svc_param=SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=0.01,C=100)
svc_param.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_svc2=svc_param.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_svc2))



"""# Decision Tree"""

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_dtree=dtree.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_dtree))
```

Model code...

```
# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
# %matplotlib inline

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import sklearn
import random

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
# %matplotlib inline


data=pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv')

sns.distplot(data['Amount'])

sns.distplot(data['Time'])

data.hist(figsize=(20,20))
plt.show()

sns.jointplot(x= 'Time', y= 'Amount', data= d)
d=data
class0 = d[d['Class']==0]

len(class0)

class1 = d[d['Class']==1]

len(class1)

class0
temp = shuffle(class0)

d1 = temp.iloc[:2000,:]

d1

frames = [d1, class1]
df_temp = pd.concat(frames)

df_temp.info()

df= shuffle(df_temp)

df.to_csv('creditcardsampling.csv')

sns.countplot('Class', data=df)

"""# SMOTE"""

#!pip install --user imblearn

import imblearn

from imblearn.over_sampling import  SMOTE
oversample=SMOTE()
X=df.iloc[ : ,:-1]
Y=df.iloc[: , -1]
X,Y=oversample.fit_resample(X,Y)

X=pd.DataFrame(X)
X.shape

Y=pd.DataFrame(Y)
Y.head()

names=['Time','V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10','V11','V12','V13','V14','V15','V16','V17','V18','V19','V20','V21','V22','V23','V24','V25','V26','V27','V28','Amount','Class']

data=pd.concat([X,Y],axis=1)

d=data.values

data=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=names)

sns.countplot('Class', data=data)

data.describe()

data.info()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
sns.heatmap(data.corr())


import math
import sklearn.preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score , classification_report, confusion_matrix, precision_recall_curve, f1_score, auc

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.drop('Class', axis=1), data['Class'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

"""# Feature Scaling"""

cols= ['V22', 'V24', 'V25', 'V26', 'V27', 'V28']

scaler = StandardScaler()

frames= ['Time', 'Amount']

x= data[frames]

d_temp = data.drop(frames, axis=1)

temp_col=scaler.fit_transform(x)

scaled_col = pd.DataFrame(temp_col, columns=frames)

scaled_col.head()

d_scaled = pd.concat([scaled_col, d_temp], axis =1)

d_scaled.head()

y = data['Class']

d_scaled.head()

"""# Dimensionality Reduction"""

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=7)

X_temp_reduced = pca.fit_transform(d_scaled)

pca.explained_variance_ratio_

pca.explained_variance_

names=['Time','Amount','Transaction Method','Transaction Id','Location','Type of Card','Bank']

X_reduced= pd.DataFrame(X_temp_reduced,columns=names)
X_reduced.head()

Y=d_scaled['Class']

new_data=pd.concat([X_reduced,Y],axis=1)
new_data.head()
new_data.shape

new_data.to_csv('finaldata.csv')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X_reduced, d_scaled['Class'], test_size = 0.30, random_state = 42)

X_train.shape, X_test.shape

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix


"""# Support Vector Machine"""

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc=SVC(kernel='rbf',probability=True)
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_svc=svc.predict(X_test)
y_pred_svc

type(X_test)
X_test.to_csv('testing.csv')
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [ {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [0.1, 1, 0.01, 0.0001 ,0.001]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = svc,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           n_jobs = -1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
print("Best Accuracy: {:.2f} %".format(best_accuracy*100))
print("Best Parameters:", best_parameters)

svc_param=SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=0.01,C=100,probability=True)
svc_param.fit(X_train,y_train)

import pickle
# Saving model to disk
pickle.dump(svc_param, open('model.pkl','wb'))

model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
```

Here is the project structure.

[image]

[image]

Here is the screenshot when i run the project into browser.
[image]

Comment: Please post the *full* error trace; from what you show in the screenshot, there is no message matching what you report, neither it is apparent *where exactly* the error pops up in the code. Do you actually call the `_probA` attribute anywhere?

Comment: I can not see the attributes in the code . let me post the other code i have into project

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely to be a versioning problem. Your scikit-learn version is probably the latest version and the `model.pkl` you downloaded from the repo you mentioned is an old and incompatible version.

To avoid this kind of problem, we should stick to best practices such as using a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file defining exactly the versions using during development. The same versions could then be installed on production.

If you really need to use this `model.pkl` from the repo, I'd suggest creating a GitHub issue asking for a `requirement.txt` file. Alternatively, you could try different scikit-learn versions until you get it working, but this can be very cumbersome.

Comment: thank you. I re develop the model with different version of SK learn . It is working